# Dynamically expand height of input type "text" based on number of characters typed into field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

Similar to the below JSFiddle (which I bookmarked and do not know from where the original question emerged):

http://jsfiddle.net/mJMpw/6/

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 10 }' />

input {
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: width 0.25s;    
}
```

Is there a way to fix the width of a text field to, for example 200px only, and have the ***height*** of the text field grow if a user adds more text than the 200px is able to contain? I would like more rows to be added, if a user needs more room to type... so I need the ***height***, not the width, to resize dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean textarea? http://flaviusmatis.github.io/flexibleArea.js/

Comment: Hi. Nope, not a textarea... I'm wondering if a single-line **input type="text"** is able to grow (similar to a textarea). Maybe, though, is textarea the only way to go? Perhaps textarea is a solution, but can it be styled to look like a regular text field at the start?

Comment: Fairly certain you cannot have a multi-line input type of text, that's what `textarea` is for. You can modify `textarea` to look like an input field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others explained, `input` field can't have multiline text, you should use `textarea` to mimic an input field, and jQuery to make it auto resize vertically (with fixed width).

**JS**:

```
//This span is used to measure the size of the textarea
//it should have the same font and text with the textarea and should be hidden
var span = $('<span>').css('display','inline-block')
                      .css('word-break','break-all')
                      .appendTo('body').css('visibility','hidden');
function initSpan(textarea){
  span.text(textarea.text())
      .width(textarea.width())
      .css('font',textarea.css('font'));
}
$('textarea').on({
    input: function(){
       var text = $(this).val();      
       span.text(text);      
       $(this).height(text ? span.height() : '1.1em');
    },
    focus: function(){           
       initSpan($(this));
    },
    keypress: function(e){
       //cancel the Enter keystroke, otherwise a new line will be created
       //This ensures the correct behavior when user types Enter 
       //into an input field
       if(e.which == 13) e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
textarea {
  width:200px;
  resize:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:18px;
  height:1.1em;
  padding:2px;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/M6SM2/3/)

### Updated Demo:

This new updated demo has some bugs fixed and it also supports Enter key, max-height limit, the width does not need to be set fixedly at first (instead we can set its min-width). It's much more full-featured.

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6SM2/488/)

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATED[2]:**

As `scrollHeight` is always equal to `height`, we have to set **height** to **'1'** before scrollHeight, then when we delete characters the `<textarea>` autofit:

```
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {e.preventDefault();}
}).on('input', function(){
    $(this).height(1);
    var totalHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
    $(this).height(totalHeight);
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mJMpw/551/

**UPDATED:**

As friends said, `<input type="text"/>` has no line breaks. My suggest using `<textarea>` is:

```
$('textarea').on({input: function(){
    var totalHeight = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
    $(this).css({'height':totalHeight});
}
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mJMpw/548/

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

this is very ugly but you could do it like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup',function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var getWidth = $('<span class="getWidth" style="white-space:nowrap; width:auto;">' + text + '</span>').insertAfter(this);
    $(this).css({'width':getWidth.outerWidth()}).next('.getWidth').remove();
});
```

You have to specify the same fonts/padding property to .getWidth and you input:

```
input, .getWidth {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    padding:3px;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9SMRf/

Comment: Thanks... but, I'm actually looking to expand the **height** of the text field.

Comment: @Berklie http://jsfiddle.net/APe4V/ Its not possible as others have said. You can not have line breaks in input fields.

Comment: well, +1 for the updated code, however looks like it can just grow, it can't shrink.

Comment: @KingKing Hi, thank you for your observation. i just fixed it. it was because scrollHeight is always equal to height. then we have to set height '1' before set scrollHeight. jsfiddle.net/mJMpw/551

Comment: @LGVentura well, looks like it's the best approach I couldn't believe. Although the technique using some dummy element (as shown in my answer) is very well-known and sometimes the only possible way but in this case it's the long way to go. In fact the `height` can be reset to any value between `0` and `1em`, really really interesting solution. this should have been accepted as the answer by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Not mine but works great:

CSS

```
textarea {
     color: #444;
     padding: 5px;
}
.txtstuff {
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hiddendiv {
    display: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word
}
.common {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.lbr {
    line-height: 3px;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="comments" placeholder="Type many lines of texts in here and you will see magic stuff" class="common"></textarea>
```

SCRIPT

```
let txt = $('#comments'),
    txt.addClass('txtstuff');
let hiddenDiv = $(document.createElement('div')),
    hiddenDiv.addClass('hiddendiv common');
let content = null;

$('body').append(hiddenDiv);

txt.on('keyup', function () {
    content = $(this).val();
    content = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    hiddenDiv.html(content + '<br class="lbr">');
    $(this).css('height', hiddenDiv.height());
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ImpressiveWebs/fGNNT/1333/)