# Wordpress post title input field to text area

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have a client adding posts with ridiculously long titles in Wordpress. The page titles are so long you can't see the whole title in the Wordpress editor page. They want to increase the size of the title input but this won't work using CSS as the text input restricts the text to 1 line. I have tried changing the title input to tinyMce editor (http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/page/add-tinymce-editor-to-postpage-title-input-field/) but that didn't work either. I don't really want to hack core theme files but the only thing left I can think of is to change the text input to a textarea field. Anyone got any ideas? Site is running WordPress 3.9.3.

Comment: You could use JS/CSS to expand the input field like textarea.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818131/dynamically-expand-height-of-input-type-text-based-on-number-of-characters-typ

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to hide the input and append a textarea on page load. Then on the texarea blure event update the hidden title field.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#titlewrap input").hide();
    $("#titlewrap").append("<textarea rows='5' cols='60'></textarea>");
    $("#titlewrap").val($("#titlewrap input").val());
    $("#titlewrap").blur(function(){
        $("#titlewrap input").val($("#titlewrap textarea").val());
    });
});
```

I didn't test the code. It is just to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks guys.. this looks like a good solution.. still can't get it to work though.. client has changed their mind now anyway.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could set its width:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 300px !important;" />
```

or even better define a class:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" class="mytext" />
```

and in a separate CSS file apply the necessary styling:

```
.mytext {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

If you want to limit the number of characters that the user can type into this textbox you could use the maxlength attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text_name" class="mytext" maxlength="25" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a script that I have used to convert input title to textarea field (that allow `<br />`).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var regexBr = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
    //Convert input to text area
    if (jQuery("#titlewrap input").val()) {
        jQuery("#titlewrap input").hide();
        jQuery("#titlewrap").append("<textarea rows='5' style='width: 100%'></textarea>");
        let regularTitle = jQuery("#titlewrap input").val().replace(regexBr, "\n");
        jQuery("#titlewrap textarea").val(regularTitle);
        jQuery("#titlewrap textarea").on('change keyup paste', function () {
            let titleWithTags = jQuery("#titlewrap textarea").val().replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
            jQuery("#titlewrap input").val(titleWithTags);
        });
    }
    //Preview index
    jQuery("strong > a").each(function (index, item) {
        item.innerText = item.innerText.replace(regexBr, "\n");
    });
});
```