# What portion of input field is occupied by the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a auto (height) increasing text field. So I need to know when to increase the height of the input field. For that I need to know if the text has already filled the input field or not. Is there a way for this ?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818131/dynamically-expand-height-of-input-type-text-based-on-number-of-characters-typ

Answer (score 0):

If it can be useful, a quick solution with a `textArea` is the next one:

Javascript:

```
function resizeText(){
  var cont = document.getElementById("mytext");
  while (cont.scrollHeight == cont.clientHeight)
  cont.rows--;

  while (cont.scrollHeight > cont.clientHeight)
  cont.rows++;
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext" rows="1" cols="30" onkeypress="resizeText()">
write here your text.
</textarea>
```