# TextArea configured to grow based on input hangs the page on large text copy paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text area in which user can type any amount of text. I want that when user adds the text to it the text area should grow automatically based on content entered. I used this implementation for that:

```
$("#message").input(function(event){

    while($(this).outerHeight() < this.scrollHeight + parseFloat($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseFloat($(this).css("borderBottomWidth"))) {
        $(this).height($(this).height()+1);
    };
});
```

This works perfectly fine as user types input to the text area, it grows automatically and scroll never appears.

But when a large text is pasted into the text area the whole page becomes unresponsive. Which I feel is due to the loop running too many times for each character.

Any fixes for this? Or Do you know some other implementation than this that fulfills both the requirements:

1. Autoheight based on input without scroll
2. Large text pasted into the text area and it grows to required size without becoming unresponsive.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically expand height of input type "text" based on number of characters typed into field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818131/dynamically-expand-height-of-input-type-text-based-on-number-of-characters-typ)

Comment: @AlivetoDie answer in the duplicate you found has the same issue

Comment: @mplungjan  hanging page issue is not there. OP' scode make his page hang

Comment: Try his updated fiddle. If I paste a lot of code the page hangs until it is updated and that took 10-15 seconds

Comment: Here is an example how to do this with plain JS.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676492/1755381

Comment: @FranzDeschler it creates the scroll

Comment: Cuz it has a max-height, just remove it

Comment: Did that but still it develops the scroll, here is the view: https://prnt.sc/g4ae8l

Comment: share a fiddle instead of a screenshot, so we can test what is wrong with it

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/un6byfuw/

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I identified the issue, some of my other css style was causing the scroll to appear.